# yii2 - Use a second model in a GridView to build a dropdown menu in a column

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-basic-app

I have two tables:

`tb_employee('employeeID', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'departmentID')` and

`tb_skills('skillID', 'week', 'ser', 'skillKnowledge','proficiency', 'instructorID')`.

In the skills view, I don't have any value in the `instructorID` column because what I want is to fill it with a dropdown menu with all the first names of employees where `departmentID=20` so that the user can choose the instructor they want. However, I have no idea how to do it, here's my code:

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  //  'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'skillID',
        'week',
        'ser',
        'skillKnowledge:ntext',
        'proficiency:ntext',
        [
                'attribute' => 'instructorID',
                'value' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 
                    'instructorID', ArrayHelper::map(app\models\TbEmployee::find()->asArray()->all(), 'employeeID', 'firstName'),
                        ['class'=>'form-control','prompt' => 'Select']),
        ],  

]); ?>
```

Comment: You want use the dropdown for filter the rows showed in gridview?

Answer (score 0):

If you want use the dropdown for filter you should use 'filter' attribute

```
'attribute' => 'attribute_name',
'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 
    'attribute_name',
     ArrayHelper::map(ModelName::find()->asArray()->all(), 'employeeID', 'firstName'),
                     ['class'=>'form-control','prompt' => 'Select']),
```